# What is meant by $f(x) = [x]$ on $[0, a]$?

Tags: calculus, notation

This exercise appears in Spivak's Calculus (4th edition, p. 130 exercise 1.11) and I'm unclear on the notation.

> Let $f(x) = [x]$ on $[0, a]$. Determine whether $f(x)$ is bounded above or below and/or takes on a maximum or minimum value in the indicated interval.

The solution is:

> $f$ has a maximum and minimum value, since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: It probably refers to the greatest integer function, i.e. $f(x)=[x] = y$, where $y$ is the unique integer such that $x-1 < y \leq x$. This is not to be confused with the interval notation $[a,b]$.

Comment: This is old notation for the floor function.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг You didn't type what you wanted to.  You don't mean $x\le[x]$

Comment: @saulspatz Will correct. Thank you.

Comment: Please add more context. The rest of the exercise may make it clear what you're expected to do with $f$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I added the question and the solution.

Comment: If $f$ is the floor function, this would contradict the solution since $f$ is discontinuous at integer values.

Comment: This is pretty strange. Does the textbook really forget to define the variable $a$? Or is it defined a couple of problems before this one? And the solution doesn't sound like a textbook solution, either. Did it come from the back of the book, or someone's notes?

Comment: @ChrisCulter This is from problem #1 in Chapter 7, and I believe $a$ can be interpreted as being a real number greater than or equal to $0$, since he wouldn't define the closed interval as $[0, a]$ if $a < 0$. The solution is from the back of the book, and is copied word for word.

Answer (score 0):

I love Spivak's Calculus!
You're absolutely right that the given function has a maximum and a minimum; however, it is not because it is continuous - the reason is far more elementary:

Suppose $f(x) = [x]$ is defined to be the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $x$; that is, given $x \geq 0$, round down, or equivalently, take its integer part. In that case, if $a = 3$, then for $x \in [0,1)$ $f(x) = 0$, for $x \in [1,2)$ $ f(x) = 1$, and $f(2) = 2$. This demonstrates that $f$, as defined, is discontinuous, and will remain discontinuous so long as $a \geq 1$.

Similar behavior is exhibited if $f$ is defined as the Ceiling function, which returns the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to the input (for example, Ceil(3.1) = 4), or if $f$ is defined to be the nearest integer function. Note that in the latter case, you need to decide what happens at positive integer multiples of $\frac{1}{2}$, as all such numbers are always equidistant from 2 unique integers.

Hope this helps!